# Flexible splitting of an input string in Python function

Tags: python, function, split

In Python, what would be the most elegant way of converting this structure:

```
['group1, group2, group3']
```

into this structure:

```
['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
```

and potentially back.

What is needed is a function that can take either a list of a string of comma separated values (first case) or a list of strings of the same values (second case) and handle them as one and the same: a list of strings.

In pseudocode:

```
x = ['group1, group2, group3']
y = ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']

f(x) <==> f(y)    <- equivalent behavior
```

Also, if using `split()` as per suggestions:

Is there a way to make the delimiter space insensitive or conditional or a regex: I'd like to get to the `['group1', 'group2', 'group3']` result in either `['group1, group2, group3']` or `['group1,group2,group3']` or even this `['group1, group2,group3']` (or a combination thereof) as an input?

A bit more clarification:

```
>>> single_string = False
>>> a = ['group1', 'group2', 'group3','group4']
>>> [t.strip() for t in [a][0].split(',')] if single_string else a
['group1', 'group2', 'group3', 'group4']
>>> single_string = True
>>> b = ['group1,group2, group3,  group4']
>>> [t.strip() for t in [b][0].split(',')] if single_string else b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
>>>
```

Basically, I'm looking for the most elegant Python conditional expression that would result in the same output both in case of `a` and `b` above:`['group1', 'group2', 'group3', 'group4']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there in your edit:

```
def f(lst):
    return [t.strip() for t in lst[0].split(',')] if len(lst) == 1 else lst

>>> a = ['group1', 'group2', 'group3','group4']
>>> b = ['group1,group2, group3,  group4']

>>> f(a)
['group1', 'group2', 'group3', 'group4']
>>> f(b)
['group1', 'group2', 'group3', 'group4']
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to get from one representation to the other:

```
print('group1, group2, group3'.split(', '))
# ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
print(', '.join(['group1', 'group2', 'group3']))
# group1, group2, group3
```

in a function you could do this:

```
def f(items, index, separator=', '):
    if isinstance(items, str):
        items = items.split(separator)
    return items[index]


print(f('group1, group2, group3', 1))        # group2
print(f(['group1', 'group2', 'group3'], 1))  # group2
```

Comment: can a separator be conditional? ', ' or ','.  I guess  a regex is more appropriate?

Comment: sure, if you need to split several things [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) should work.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

#### Code:

```
['group1, group2, group3'][0].split(', ')
```

#### Test Code:

```
x = ['group1, group2, group3']    
print(x[0].split(', '))
```

#### Results:

```
['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
```

#### To return:

To return use `str.join()`

```
y = x[0].split(', ')
print(y)

xx = [', '.join(y)]
print(xx)
```

#### Results:

```
['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
['group1, group2, group3']
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to make the delimiter space insensitive: I'd like to get to the `['group1', 'group2', 'group3']` result in either `['group1, group2, group3']` or `['group1,group2,group3']` or even this `['group1,  group2,group3']` (or a combination thereof) as an input?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon You can split on the bare comma and strip the tokens: `y = [t.strip() for t in x[0].split(',')`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Your comment seems to be the closest to what I'm after - you may want to make it into an official answer, I've updated my question with a bit more clarification if you care to take another look.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on `,` followed by flattening of result using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> f = lambda x: list(chain(*[a.split(', ') for a in x]))

>>> f(['group1', 'group2', 'group3'])
>>> ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']

>>> f(['group1, group2, group3'])
>>> ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
```

In case of variable separator and optional space, regex would be a better choice

```
>>> import re
>>> f = lambda x, sep: list(chain(*[re.split('{}\s*'.format(sep), a) for a in x]))
>>> f(['group1, group2,group3'],',')
>>> ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
```

Answer (score 0):

split() and join() can try .

```
case1 = ['group1, group2, group3']
output = [ele.split(",") for ele in case1]
```

Output for case-1

```
[['group1', ' group2', ' group3']]
```

Case-2

```
case2 = [['group1', ' group2', ' group3']]
output = [", ".join(ele) for ele in case2]
```

Output for case-2

```
['group1, group2, group3']
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `str.replace()` to eliminate all white spaces you can use a formula that will work on all cases presented.

```
lst = ['group1, group2, group3']

res = lst[0].replace(' ', '').split(',')
# ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's most clear simply using `split` and `strip`.

```
# various scenarios to test
TESTS = [
    ['group1, group2, group3'],
    ['group1', 'group2', 'group3'],
    ['group1,group2,  group3'],
    ['group1', 'group2, group3'],
    ['group1 ,group2', 'group3'],
]


def normalize(args, delimiter=','):
    results = []
    for arg in args:
        results.extend(x.strip() for x in arg.split(delimiter))
    return results


for args in TESTS:
    assert normalize(args) == ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']


# test alternative delimiter
assert normalize(['group1 | group2 | group3'], delimiter='|') == ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']
```